# How to prove that helicity is conserved for massive Dirac particles

Tags: conservation-laws, hamiltonian, dirac-equation, dirac-matrices, helicity

The helicity is defined as:
$$h=\frac{\vec{S}.\vec{p}}{||\vec{p}||}$$ where $$S= \frac{\hbar}{2} \zeta$$ and $\zeta$ equals
\begin{pmatrix}
\vec{\sigma} & 0\\
0 & \vec{\sigma}
\end{pmatrix}
where $\sigma$ is equal to the Pauli-matrices.

I have to prove that $h$ is conserved, the way I wanted to do this is by showing that $h$ commutes with the Dirac Hamiltonian: $$[h,H]=hH-Hh=0$$
The Dirac Hamiltonian is equal to:
$$H = c\gamma^0(\vec{\gamma}.\vec{p}+mc)$$
I then get:
$$[h,H] = \frac{c\hbar}{2} \zeta \gamma^0(\vec{\gamma}\vec{p}+mc)- \frac{c\hbar}{2}\gamma^0(\vec{\gamma}\vec{p}+mc)\zeta$$
I don't know how to further work out this expression.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks like you have substituted $h ~ \zeta$ in your last expression, when it should be $h ~ \vec{\zeta} \cdot \vec{p} $. Also, you should know how to write $\vec{\gamma}$ in terms of the Pauli spin matrices - try doing this. It might help to write out the dot products explicitly.

Comment: Thank you very much! I now find: $$\frac{c\hbar}{2} \begin{pmatrix}
mc \vec{\sigma}.\hat{p} & \vec{\sigma}.\hat{p} \vec{\sigma}.\vec{p}\\
\vec{\sigma}.\hat{p} \vec{\sigma}.\vec{p} & -mc \vec{\sigma}.\hat{p}
\end{pmatrix}$ - $\frac{c\hbar}{2} \begin{pmatrix}
mc \vec{\sigma}.\hat{p} & \vec{\sigma}.\vec{p} \vec{\sigma}.\hat{p}\\
\vec{\sigma}.\vec{p} \vec{\sigma}.\hat{p} & -mc \vec{\sigma}.\hat{p}
\end{pmatrix}$$ for the commutation between $h$ and $H$.

I guess that these matrices cancel each other out, which gives 0?